# Convert long to "unsigned, 4 byte integer in network byte order" with ByteBuffer

Tags: java, nio, bit-shift, bytebuffer

The protocol I'm using requires sending back the current position in a file as a "unsigned, 4 byte integer in network byte order". There are several questions on this, but they are assuming I'm using Integers, not Longs

I am attempting to port this to NIO's ByteBuffer so it can be sent in the socket channel:

```
long bytesTransfered = ... some number of bytes transfered...
//TODO: What does this actually do?
outBuffer[0] = (byte) ((bytesTransfered >> 24) & 0xff);
outBuffer[1] = (byte) ((bytesTransfered >> 16) & 0xff);
outBuffer[2] = (byte) ((bytesTransfered >> 8) & 0xff);
//TODO: Why does netbeans say this does nothing?
outBuffer[3] = (byte) ((bytesTransfered >> 0) & 0xff);
```

Are their any methods in ByteBuffer that accomplish this? Hopefully in a more obvious, self-descriptive way then the bit-shifting magic above?

Comment: If you are using `long` why do you only want 4 bytes? Conversely, if you only want 4 bytes it is pointless to insist on `long`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether signed or unsigned, the bits are the same.

If you cast a `long` to an `int`, the JVM discards the high-order bits. The issue comes when promoting an `int` to a `long`: Java will sign-extend the value, filling in the high-order bits of the `long` with the most-significant bit of the `int`.

To resolve this problem, simply apply a mask to the long. The following should make this clear:

```
long value = Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1234L;
System.out.println("original value    = " + value);

int iValue = (int)value;
System.out.println("value as int      = " + iValue);
byte[] array = new byte[4];

ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(array);
buf.putInt(0, iValue);

int iRetrieved = buf.getInt(0);
System.out.println("int from buf      = " + iRetrieved);

long retrieved = iRetrieved;
System.out.println("converted to long = " + retrieved);

retrieved = retrieved & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
System.out.println("high bytes masked = " + retrieved);
```

*However*, be aware that you still have only 32 bits. If the filesizes is greater than 4Gb you won't be able to fit it into 4 bytes (and if you have to worry about files > 2G, then you should worry about files > 4G).

Answer (score 3):

That's exactly what [`ByteBuffer.putInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putInt%28int%29) is for. You say you're using `long` but you also only want to write four bytes, so you'll have to cast your `long` to `int`. Or else use `putLong()` and get 8 bytes.

Comment: Look at the other deleted answer. Literally the second sentence says "There are several questions on this, **but they are assuming I'm using Integers, not Longs**"

Comment: I guess the problem is that in Java int is signed. The protocol is assuming that I'm using unsigned ints and can therefore support file sizes larger than 2gb. The long requirement doesn't exist because its shiny, it exists for a reason

Comment: @TheLQ - nothing about your comment changes the validity of this answer.  the bits for an int are the same, signed or unsigned.

Comment: @TheLQ An unsigned int takes 32 bits. A signed int takes 32 bits. That's four bytes in both cases. The presence or absence of the sign makes no difference on the wire. You do need to grasp this point. You specified four bytes yourself. That's what putInt() does. QED and end of discussion, all present and future downvotes notwithstanding.

Comment: @jtahlborn and EJP I've reversed my downvote, a test program of several values comparing the ByteBuffer's array after casting and putInt with the code in the question yields equal arrays. At least this shows why I wanted to change this code: I still don't understand storage at the byte level. I'm accepting the other answer simply because it gives way more detail

Comment: *Of course* your test yields equal byte arrays. There is no mechanism via which it could fail to do so. If you didn't know that a Java int occupies four bytes, whether signed or unsigned, you were not competent to be downvoting answers in the first place. *Every answer* you've received here, *including* @Evgeniy Dorofeev's deleted answer (which I have voted to undelete), has been correct. Only your question was wrong here. It just goes to show, again, that questioners are usually the last people to be able to judge correct answers.

Comment: @EJP - that last sentence is soooo true.